# How to call function from within a partialview that reloads the partialview itself

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a MVC Index View with a link that, on click, calls a JQuery method that fires off an Ajax POST to dynamically load a PartialView into a div.

**Inside** the PartialView I have a form that, when submitted, needs to reload itself (the PartialView), into the div in the Index View.

When I try the code below it gives a memory exception in Visual Studio.

How do I 'reload' the partialview like this?  Can I reference the div in the main (containing) View from the PartialView?

Relevant code snippets below

**Index View**

```
<a href="#" class="buttonId currentplayer" data-userteamid="60" data-footballclub="" data-searchstring="">click to load game 60</a> 

<div id="teampartial"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var returnTeam = function (link) {
    debugger;
    var userTeamId = $(link).attr('data-userteamid');
    var footballClub = $(link).attr('data-footballclub');
    var searchString = $(link).attr('data-searchstring');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ViewPlayers/TeamOverView',
        data: {
            userTeamId: userTeamId,
            footballClub: footballClub,
            searchString: searchString
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#teampartial').empty();
            $('#teampartial').append(data);
        }
    });
};

$('.buttonId').click(function () {
    returnTeam(this);
});
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TeamOverView(int userTeamId, string footballClub, string searchString)
    {
        var _teamOverView = _service.GetTeamOverViewViewModel((int)userTeamId, footballClub, searchString);
        return PartialView("teamdetails", _teamOverView);
    }
```

**Team Details PartialView**

```
<h2>List of Players</h2>
            using (Html.BeginForm("TeamOverView", "ViewPlayers", FormMethod.Post,new { id = "filterPlayers" }))
            {
                <p> 
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Clubs, new SelectList(Model.Clubs,"Value","Text"), "All")
                    Name: @Html.TextBox("searchString") 
                    <input type="hidden" name="userTeamID" value="@Model.UserTeamId" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
                </p>
            }
            <table>
                @foreach (var item in Model.PlayersSearchedFor)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var returnSelectTeam = function () {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ViewPlayers/TeamOverView',
            data: $("#filterPlayers").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#teampartial').empty();
                $('#teampartial').append(data);
            }
        });
    };

    $('#filterPlayers').submit(function () {
        returnSelectTeam();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `Ajax.BeginForm`

**Team Details PartialView**

```
<h2>List of Players</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("TeamOverView", "ViewPlayers", new AjaxOptions { 
HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "teampartial", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
        {
            <p> 
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Clubs, new SelectList(Model.Clubs,"Value","Text"), "All")
                Name: @Html.TextBox("searchString") 
                <input type="hidden" name="userTeamID" value="@Model.UserTeamId" />
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
            </p>
        }
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in Model.PlayersSearchedFor)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

What this will do is send an ajax post of your form data, and take the result and replace the target with the result.

So make sure your response in your action is something like:

```
return PartialView("PartialViewName");
```

Here is some [sample code and tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PartialView-and-Ajax-bb05c909)

Comment: No - I already know how to load content into a div (from the index view I load a partialview into a div using JQuery rather than Microsoft.Ajax ) - what I'm having an issue with is I also have a form *inside* the loaded partialview that needs to 'reload' the partialview into the div in the 'containing' index view.

Comment: As I said before, if you use Ajax.BeginFrom instead it will work just fine. I have updated my question with your code. The Ajax.BeginForm doesn't care that it is inside a partialview.

Comment: Ah. Apologies for my previous comment then.  Could you explain why it is possible to do this with Ajax.BeginForm but not JQuery?

Comment: I've just tried this and it replaces the entire page with the partialview, rather than refreshing the teamdetails div.  Could this be because, inside the partialview, it cannot find the element with id 'teamdetails' (because that div is in the containing 'Index' view)??

Comment: Nope it should work just fine, also you can of course do it with jQuery but the MVC framework does it out the box so its not necessary in this case (unless you need something custom) follow the tutorial above, i think it covers it all.